# How to get value of optional in Swift

Tags: swift, string

```
let userId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userId")
let path = "images/\(userId!)/\(UUID().uuidString).jpg"
```

I have this code where I specify a path, by using **userId**. But since its stored in `UserDefaults` it is an optional. But when i force-unwrap it, I get this:

> **Optional(someValue)** instead of **someValue**

**Any ideas on how to just get the value?**

**UPDATE**
This is how I initialy store the value:

```
func verifyCode(code: String) {

self.isLoadingVerify.toggle()

let verificationId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "verificationId") ?? ""
let credentials = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationId, verificationCode: code)

Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials) { (authResult, error) in
    
    self.isLoadingVerify.toggle()
    
    if error != nil {
        self.isError.toggle()
        self.errorMsg = error?.localizedDescription ?? ""
        return
    }
    
    print(authResult ?? "")
    
    self.userId = String(describing: authResult?.user.uid)
    
    self.isVerify.toggle()
    self.isVerified.toggle()
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
let userId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userId")
let path = "images/\(userId!)/\(UUID().uuidString).jpg"
```

can only be `Optional(someValue)` if you have saved the `userId` previously with String Interpolation like

```
UserDefaults.standard(set: "\(userId)", forKey: "userId")
```

while `userId` is `String?`

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet:

```
let userId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userId")
let path = "images/\(userId!)/\(UUID().uuidString).jpg"
```

Will result in two cases:

1. if "*userId*" is nil, then force unwrap will lead to the app crash
2. if "*userId*" has value, then force unwrap returns string without "Optional" word

Your problematic string output will be present only when "*userId*" will not force unwrap:

```
let path = "images/\(userId)/\(UUID().uuidString).jpg"
```

While creating your question, you probably passed the wrong code snippet or string output.